# Is it posible to set a ComplexObject property to null?

Tags: breeze

I have a breeze Entity that has a data property that is a complex object itself. when creating the entity breeze creates a complex object with the default values for that property. I want to make it null, is it posible????
Thanks in advance!!!
Tony

Answer (score 0):

No, a complex property cannot be null, because it is conceptually a value type. We also wanted to make sure that you could always navigation thru a complex type.  i.e. that you never have to worry about null checking a complex property path. For example: aCompany.Address.City where the 'Address' property is a complex type will never throw an exception because 'Address' can never be null.

What you can do is set all of the properties within a complex type to null ( or default values), and write logic to handle a complex object that matches these characteristics.

Hope this makes sense.